# Storing Client API Keys AngularJs Securely in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJs but I've researched and studied everything online for it to be power my back-end API services (PHP). The problem I'm having is that I am using Oauth2 (Bshaffer Library) to implement security. Before moving to AngJs, there was no problem with storing the client id and client secret serverside, however I'm weary of how I will store these client keys on my applications (web or hybrid apps). I plan on using Angular-storage to store the tokens specifically, so that isn't a problem, but what about client keys?

I have spent ages researching this with no real clues, the article on most Google searches was written by some idiot that made his own OAuth styled implementation which was completely insecure so I thought I had to come here and ask.

Thanks